# Running systemd in a Docker managed plugin

Tags: docker, plugins, containerd

How do you run `systemd` in a [Docker managed plugin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/)?  With a normal container I can run [centos/systemd](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/) and run an Apache server using their example Dockerfile

```
FROM centos/systemd
RUN yum -y install httpd; yum clean all; systemctl enable httpd.service
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

And running it as follows

```
docker build --rm --no-cache -t httpd .
docker run --privileged --name httpd -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -p 80:80 -d  httpd
```

However, when I try to make a managed plugin, there are some issues with the cgroups

I've tried putting in the `config.json`

```
    {
        "destination": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "source": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "type": "bind",
        "options": [
            "bind",
            "ro",
            "private"
        ]
    }

    {
        "destination": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "source": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "type": "bind",
        "options": [
            "bind",
            "ro",
            "rprivate"
        ]
    }

    {
        "destination": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "source": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "type": "bind",
        "options": [
            "rbind",
            "ro",
            "rprivate"
        ]
    }
```

I also tried the following which damages the host's cgroup which may require a hard reboot to recover.

```
    {
        "destination": "/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd",
        "source": "/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd",
        "type": "bind",
        "options": [
            "bind",
            "ro",
            "private"
        ]
    }

    {
        "destination": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "source": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "type": "bind",
        "options": [
            "bind",
            "ro",
            "private"
        ]
    }
```

It looks to be something to do with how opencontainer and moby interact https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it on my https://github.com/trajano/docker-volume-plugins/tree/master/centos-mounted-volume-plugin

The key thing to do is preserve the `/run/docker/plugins` before `systemd` gets started and wipes the `/run` folder. Then make sure you create the socket in the new folder.

```
mkdir -p /dockerplugins
if [ -e /run/docker/plugins ]
then
  mount --bind /run/docker/plugins /dockerplugins
fi
```

The other thing is that Docker managed plugins add an implicit `/sys/fs/cgroup` **AFTER** the defined mounts in config so creating a readonly mount will not work unless it was rebound before starting up systemd.

```
mount --rbind /hostcgroup /sys/fs/cgroup
```

With the mount defined in config.json as

```
{
        "destination": "/hostcgroup",
        "source": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "type": "bind",
        "options": [
            "bind",
            "ro",
            "private"
        ]
}
```

Creating the socket needs to be customized since the plugin helpers write to `/run/docker/plugins`

```
l, err := sockets.NewUnixSocket("/dockerplugins/osmounted.sock", 0)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
h.Serve(l)
```

The following shows the process above on how I achieved it on my plugin

- https://github.com/trajano/docker-volume-plugins/blob/v1.2.0/centos-mounted-volume-plugin/init.sh
- https://github.com/trajano/docker-volume-plugins/blob/v1.2.0/centos-mounted-volume-plugin/config.json
- https://github.com/trajano/docker-volume-plugins/blob/v1.2.0/centos-mounted-volume-plugin/main.go#L113

Answer (score -1):

You can run httpd in a centos container without systemd - atleast to the tests with the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script.

Comment: I am using httpd as an example for a systemd service.  I am writing my own service.

Comment: I am using it with quite a number of service scripts - both from known applications and the ones under development.

Comment: Except the question I asking is for the context of a Docker managed plugin.  Not a typical container.

Comment: Well, then you may have to explain what you mean with a "docker managed plugin" because your examples still make a good match for an executable running in a container. ;)